Why is it my custom css code not working?
I tried to add a custom css for a certain css using elementor for menu viewport
I tried to input this code to elementor custom css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .elementor-1798 .elementor-element.elementor-element-2b9e1e5d {
        width: 62% !important;
    }
}

But when i refresh the custom css code that I input didn't work/applied
